# How to get just one category and not all of them

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the problem:

I've been using this code to get other posts to display in the end of the page (as a list), and those posts should be in the same category as the post that a visitor is currently reading. It works fine, but the problem that occurs is when the post is assigned to multiple categories, then I have multiple listings which is not needed.

How can I restrict this , to just one category (by name, or by id or the first one), so that the loop shows me posts from just one category when post with multiple categories is displayed?

Many thx.

```
<?php global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category) :
?>
<h3 class="naslovostalih">Ostali članci iz ove kategorije:</h3>
<ul class="clanciostalih">

<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&category='. $category->term_id);
foreach($posts as $post) :
?>
<li>
<?php
$title = get_the_title($ID);
$link = get_permalink();
printf('<a class="linkpost" title="%s" href="%s">%s</a>', $title, $link, $title);
the_post_thumbnail('thumb-232');
echo '<div id="excerptcu">';
echo excerpt(25);
echo '</div>';
?>
<p class="more-link-wrapper2"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more     button"><?php _e( 'Opširnije &raquo;', 'fearless' ); ?></a></p>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the category id to get_posts just as in your code

Instead of looping the categories try like below: here 3 is the category id

```
$posts = get_posts('category=3&numberposts=10');
```

Also if you want to retrieve the category id of specific category by name you can use

`get_cat_ID( $cat_name )`

Comment: Thx for your advice, it works but , the category is not always 3 or 4 etc. I need it to get the category from current post and then display other posts which are in the same category.

Comment: You need a category wise listing of posts?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could just take the first category in your foreach loop instead of iterating through all of them? You can do this by setting a variable like

```
$first = true;
```

Before your loop. Then, set your foreach loop in an "if" that checks to see if $first == false. If so, do the loop. In your loop, do your stuff and set $first = true and it will only iterate once.

Comment: Could you use my code and write the change you just suggested please? Thank you.